# How to make title row of crosstab invisible

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, reportbuilder

I have designed the following crosstab in my report:[image]

Is there a way I can make the first (title) row invisible (the row that mentions ‘Sum of resultaat’ and ‘volgnumm’).
I have no clue how to achieve this…

Comment: you should have an onprint event. From the report builder pdf - "The events for each of the components and bands
are codeable, which means that if you inserted
code for the OnPrint event of the label, that code
would execute when the label printed."

Comment: Yeah, but the ppCrosstab component has only a general 'on print' event, not one specific for the title row, or any row or column specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got word from Nard Moseley from digital-metaphors that it's impossible to do at this moment:

> "There are no properties or events to control that. You could set the captions to empty string, but no way to delete the row entirely."

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which version of ReportBuilder you are using, but I've had a look at my version here (Version 10) and the CrossTab component does appear quite limited in terms of customisation.

However, ReportBuilder is quite well structured and a quick look at the ppCTRend.pas file reveals that it should be possible to create your own custom renderer derived from `TppCustomCrossTabRenderer` (remembering to register the rendering class with a call to `ppRegisterRenderer`). Methods to look at would be `AddTextToPage` and `DrawCells`